# r-Markdown (pagenumbering, thumb-index)

Tags: latex, r-markdown, markdown, pandoc

I want the pagenumber to display like this:

[image: Screenshot 1]

I have r-markdown like this:

```
---
LaTeX code here
---
Markdown code here
```

The actual code:

```
---
header-includes:
- \usepackage{geometry}
- \usepackage{fancyhdr}
- \usepackage{graphicx}
- \usepackage{xcolor}
- \geometry{
        a4paper,
        left=15mm,
        right=15mm,
        headheight=3cm,
        top=4cm,
        bottom=4.5cm,
        footskip=1cm,
    }
- \pagestyle{fancy}
- \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.4pt}
- \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.4pt}
- \fancyhead[R]{\includegraphics[width=3.5cm]{logo.png}}
- \fancyfoot[L]{multiple Details \\ multiple Details \\ multiple Details}
- \fancyfoot[C]{multiple Details \\ multiple Details \\ multiple Details}
- \fancyfoot[R]{multiple Details \\ multiple Details \\ multiple Details}
output: pdf_document
---

# Heading level 1

content

## Heading level 2

content

# Heading level 1

content

## Heading level 2

content
```

**My question:
Which package do I use and how is it possible to display my pagenumber like in the screenshot?**

To convert the .md file to a .pdf I use pandoc like this:

```
pandoc --toc readme.md -o readme.pdf
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your distribution is reasonable new (within the last year or so...), you can use the `shipout/foreground` hook to create such a thumb index for the page number (make sure to compile two times to get the position right):

```
---
header-includes:
- \usepackage{geometry}
- \usepackage{fancyhdr}
- \usepackage{graphicx}
- \usepackage{xcolor}
- \geometry{
        a4paper,
        left=15mm,
        right=15mm,
        headheight=3cm,
        top=4cm,
        bottom=4.5cm,
        footskip=1cm,
    }
- \pagestyle{fancy}
- \fancyhead[R]{\includegraphics[width=3.5cm]{example-image-duck}}
- \fancyfoot[L]{multiple Details \\ multiple Details \\ multiple Details}
- \fancyfoot[C]{multiple Details \\ multiple Details \\ multiple Details}
- \fancyfoot[R]{multiple Details \\ multiple Details \\ multiple Details}
- \usepackage{tikzpagenodes}
- \usepackage{lastpage}
- \AddToHook{shipout/foreground}{\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]\node[draw,rotate=90,minimum width=3cm,anchor=north] at (current page text area.east) {\thepage\ / \pageref{LastPage} }; \end{tikzpicture}}
output: 
  pdf_document:
    keep_tex: true
---

# Heading level 1

content

## Heading level 2

content

# Heading level 1

content

## Heading level 2

content
```

[image]

Comment: Copied! Doesnt compile. Im using MiKTeX. Is that okay? Updating it rn!
Didn't update for a while.

Comment: @PhilipKönig Miktex is fine, it just needs to be new enough, say within the last year or so

Comment: Miktex isnt working for me. It failed to install updates. Also tried to uninstall and install new. What would be an alternativ recommended by you?

Comment: Personally I'm using https://tug.org/texlive/ This is available on all platforms, much better tested and seems to be less prone to packaging errors as miktex.

Comment: Thank you so much for your time, everything seems to be working rn!

Comment: @PhilipKönig You're welcome! Nice to hear it is working!

Comment: What would the command look like without the box around the pagenumbers? So only like 1/12? @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz

Comment: remove the `draw`

Comment: Last Question, sorry to bother you: Its overlapping with the text. How can I move the 1/12 more to the right side of the a4 paper so it doesnt overlap? @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz